# Voltage on connected battery terminals

Tags: batteries, series

I have a series connected battery:

[image]

I would expect there is no voltage on upper terminals, but when I measured there was 0.2V.
Terminals are connected with screws and bus bar. I tried tightening the screw, which led it to ~0.05V.
How is it possible? The metal parts are touching each other, why is there voltage difference?

Comment: Crappy probes to your voltmeter could be the reason.

Answer (score 2):

If there is any current flowing, there will be a voltage difference between the two terminals because of the voltage drop across the non-zero resistance of the bus bar.

V = I * R

Even when R is really small.

The negative voltage is likely measurement error.